# Block visibility using PHP to show Vocabulary and Terms not working

Tags: 7, blocks

In Drupal 6 I used PHP for Block visibility on selected vocabularies and terms.

The same PHP code does not work in Drupal 7 on a Centos 7 computer. Does PHP 4.4. not work on a PHP 4.5 server? I am using the same examples found here:
https://www.drupal.org/comment/reply/69076#comment-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to consider using the "[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)" module, then you shouldn't need that "PHP code" anymore (sometimes a solution to a problem is to just avoid the problem from happening ...). Provided you can express your actual "logic" (about selected terms?) in appropriate Rules logic of course (as is often the case). More details about doing so are explained below.

## Part 1: Rules block visibility

Have a look at the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless:
>
> - Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
> - Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
> - What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) implement the "PHP code" logic you used before.

## Part 2: Create an appropriate Rules Component

The [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module doesn't have a lot of documentation, except in the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules_block_visibility/tree/README.txt#n24) that comes with this module. Here is what the crucial part of it is (to get the idea):

> Configuration is done on a per-block basis. To control a block
>   visibility using a rule component, go to the block settings page,
>   scroll down to the "Rules" tab, and select the Rules component that
>   you want to use.
>
> Notice that to be able to be used by this module, a Rules component
>   *must* be constructed in a very specific way. See the [next section](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules_block_visibility/tree/README.txt#n36) for
>   more information.

This module comes with 2 sample Rules Components, that should help to understand the concept behind it.

By looking at these samples, I was able to create another Rules Component which looks like so:

```
{ "rules_block_visibility_hide_block_for_user_1" : {
    "LABEL" : "Hide block for user 1",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:uid" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```

You should be able to import this rule in your own environment.

What this Rules Component does is "only" return a boolean (**1** or **0**), based on the condition if the user's uid is YES or NO equal to `1`.

With that, we're coming close to an actual answer to your question. All that needed is to massage your "PHP code" in an equivalent (set of) Rules Condition(s) (+ use that instead of the sample condition in my sample above), and then continue with Part 3 below.

## Part 3:

Head over to the "Block" settings for the block you want to conditionally hide. At the bottom of it's settings, within the typical "Visibility settings", there is now (after you enabled the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module as in Part 1) an extra tab labeled "*Rules*". Using that tab will allow you to select a "Rules Component" that will do what's documented below that selection list field, ie: "***Show this block only if the selected rule returns a positive value. Important: to be listed here, a block visibility rule must have specific parameters and return values.***".

And guess what, in my case I just selected my Rules Component from Part 2

**Note**: it doesn't matter what type of block it is (created by a view, or something else), it works in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Modules written for Drupal 6 are not designed to work with Drupal 7. Some do, by fluke, but it's quite rare. Sounds like you have one of the more common ones, that doesn't.

I'm not sure what you mean by

> Does php4.4. not work on a php4.5 server?

I think you're confusing several things there, none of which would be related to Drupal.

If you want to know what versions of PHP Drupal supports, see the [requirements](https://www.drupal.org/requirements). If you want to know what version your server supports, your hosting provider will be able to tell you.

Some modules have specific minimum PHP version requirements; you can find those in the module's .info file, and you'll also be informed in the UI if your system can't support it.

Comment: My php version are wrong. My old d6 site was using php PHP 5.3 and running on a Centos 6 server. Now my upgraded d7 site run on a Centos 7 server with php 5 .4.16. I think the old php syntax will not work any more